# Data handling of list + details + edit views in a EmberJS app

Tags: javascript, data-binding, ember.js

I'm building an EmberJS app which needs to have three components. A list of items, a detailed view of each item and an edit view of each item. I haven't found any good explanation or example of how to manage the data in this particular case.

You can find a simplified and cleaned out example of what I've got right now at this gist: https://gist.github.com/2390740

What I'd like to avoid is having two copies of the data, but the only way I've been able to get the data into the detailed view is by making a copy of it, which is far from ideal.

Is there some way to reference an item in the array in the ListController from DetailController? That way when the item is updated in the detailed view the list view is automatically updated with the changes.

What I would like to achieve is that the ListController loads a list with basic information about each item, and then the DetailController loads all the available info for the selected item. If the client side data store could be the same for both the list and the detailed view, the DetailController wouldn't have to load the detailed info again if the user returns to an item which already has been loaded. Another benefit is that the list view would already be up to date if the user changed anything and then returns to the list.

Note: I know that the edit view is missing in this example, I'm just trying to get the data binding between the detailed view and the list to work first.

Comment: I found a slightly better way to do this by changing currentItem into a computed property and only copying the index to the current item. This is more of what I was trying to achieve but I'll leave the question of there's an even better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly this in my [feed reader ember application](https://github.com/mattkatz/Wordprss). 
The way to do this is have a detailController with a content property.
Bind all your detail view stuff to the detailController.  Selecting an item in the listcontroller should set the content property of the detailcontroller to that item.  Done!